# Создание ветки через Git в Github

Tags: git, github

Нужно создать ветку в проекте на GITHUB
Вот пишу в git bash команду

```
$ git checkout -b SergeiKhyliuk
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишет что switched...
Я так понимаю нужно еще отправить это на github?
Потому что в ветках на github моей ветки нету

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В sourcetree тоже не показывает...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы [отправить](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Pushing-to-Your-Remotes) вашу созданную локальную ветку(SergeiKhyliuk) на удаленный репозиторий выполните

```
git push origin SergeiKhyliuk
```

Comment: Я так и сделал, а потом удалил )) Мне не нравится что там у других в колонке другая зависимость или что это... И создательветки пишет не мое имятак как у других, а того кто мастер ветку создал https://i.gyazo.com/abdb0115f1c4fddb4bcf439dcc2c7ef7.png

Comment: По скриншоту, выделенная колонка показывает, от черты значение слева - сколько коммитов влито в default ветку из этой ветки(master), справа - сколько коммитов в ветке, которые еще не влиты в default ветку. В сумме значения дают общее количество коммитов в ветке

Comment: действительно, как комит добавил, все ок, такая особенность Гита и создатель ветки на мое имя изменился